# Haxe - компиляция в другие языки

Tags: actionscript-3, php, javascript

Про Haxe я слышал много раз, но в плотную узнавать о нём не хотел, до одного события.
В "одном языке" есть фреймворк написанный на Haxe и работающий в несколько раз быстрее аналогов, написанных на родном языке. То есть как это? - задал я себе вопрос - как это написан на Haxe? После этого я полез в гугл и прочел, что код Haxe можно компилировать под JS,AS3,PHP... И остановившись на этом я решил спросить Вас - действительно ли код, написанный на Haxe и скомпилированный в другой язык, будет быстрее и лучше?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haxe генерит исходник на заданном языке программирования. А так, как он генерит **текст**, то это значит, что всегда найдется программист, который сможет написать текст как минимум "не хуже". Поэтому, ответ на вопрос

> действительно ли код, написанный на Haxe и скомпилированный в другой язык, будет быстрее и лучше?

простой - нет.

Но здесь есть один хитрый плюс. (все, написанное ниже не относиться напрямую к haxe, а к некому универсальному компилятору)

Дело в том, что генератору достаточно просто генерировать большие однотипные куски. К примеру, генератор знает, что компиялтор языка "ХХХ" не умеет разворачивать циклы. А разворачивание мелких циклов иногда дает нехилый прирост.

Или, к примеру, компилятор может упрощать арифметические выражения, делать распараллеливания и тому подобное.

Но как же так получилось, что

> работающий в несколько раз быстрее аналогов

Возможно, просто человек, который писал код, хорошо понимал, что он делал. Я более чем уверен, что если бы написать на оригинальном языке эквивалентную библиотеку, то вышло бы не хуже по скорости.

Но ещё нужно не забывать, что некоторые люди любят подганять тесты. Они специально выбирают такие наборы входных данных, когда их любимый язык впереди. Парочка моих любимых примеров. Зайдите в украинскую википедию и посмотрите на код вычисления [функции эйлера](http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%95%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0). Она там на с и pascal. Они вычисляют одно и тоже, но вот только си версия во много раз быстрее. Складывается ложное впечатление. А небольшой анализ показывает, что там два, абсолютно разных способа. И си версия, переписанная на паскаль работает также быстро.

На второй пример я попался сам, когда мне показали простую программу на java и на си, которая по факту просто суммирует элементы последовательности. Они визуально почти идентичны. Но только java версия работала в полтора раза быстрее си версии, скомпилированной с `-O3`. А секрет оказался прост. Java компилятор умудрился распараллелить на два потока, так как заметил, что расчеты элементов в теле цикла независимы. Но достаточно было запустить параллельно несколько программ, как все стало на свои места. Мораль - то, что в синтетическом тесте круто работает не обязательно при боевой нагрузке будет работать также быстро.

Comment: @KoVadim: Спасибо! Сам бы не додумался про то, что это компилятор оптимизирует код.